# MySQL NodeJS Openshift server - query to database seems to not be working

Tags: mysql, node.js, openshift

I have a nodejs server in Openshift with a MySQL cartridge. It seems to build with no problem, however, when I try to query the database, it seems to be doing nothing... It doesn't even give me an error, it's just does nothing. Here's my relevant code.

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'mysql://' + process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST + ':' + process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT + '/',
    user: process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD,
    database: 'revision',
    multipleStatements: true,
    debug : true
});
```

And in the appropriate route:

```
var stuff = 'abc';
connection.query('SELECT 1', function(err, rows, fields){
    if (err) {
        stuff = "ghi";
    } else {
        stuff = "def";
    }
});
stuff = stuff + "done";
res.send(JSON.stringify(stuff));
```

It should return "defdone" or "ghidone", but it always returns "abcdone"... It's like it doesn't even get inside the function. I've tried several ways of doing this and none work. I've dumped the connection variable and it seems to be what's meant to be.

The reason I'm using SELECT 1 as the query string was to verify it was not a database error.

Comment: Are you calling the `connection.connect()` before the query?

Comment: Yes. And the connection.end() after too. I didn't put it on this post because I read somewhere that query() implicitly calls them, so I thought they were irrelevant code. However, I have them in the script.

Comment: please consider removing your EDIT and adding it as an answer to your own question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the "issue" had to do with the asynchronous nature of node, as the final 2 instructions are executed before the query is completed. Furthermore, the configs seemed to be wrong after all, as I only had a "host" attribute with the whole url. I changed it into to 2 attributes - "host and "port", giving them the appropriate variables (process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST and process.env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT). It's working now!